# Disable ECB flyout menu in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

SharePoint 2013 introduced a new flyout on list items instead of a drop-down context menu. When you click the 3 dots next to a list item or document, you get the flyout. You then have to click the 3 dots on THAT flyout to get the normal old-fashioned context menu.

If at all possible, I need to eliminate that extra click and just have the first 3 dots open the full context menu for the item. I've been googling on this for three days with no success yet.

I'm not that keen of a developer yet, but if it can be done via JSLink, modifying OOTB JS files or CSS, I can probably figure it out with some guidance.

Is there a way to eliminate the middle-man here and just have the context/ECB menu open from the first 3-dot-click?

Comment: ms has the habit of adding html to the page only after items are clicked, which being the case, will not be an easy job. anyway, +1 for the question

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here are my 2 cents

CSS

```
<style>
/*bonus - show menu item icons*/
.ms-core-menu-link * {display: inline !important;}

/*hide the first flyout*/
.js-callout-mainElement{visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

Script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //first click
    $('.ms-lstItmLinkAnchor').click(function(event){

        console.log('first click');

        //trigger second click
        if($(this).next('.js-callout-mainElement').length > 0)
        {
            console.log('unecessary first flyout found');

            //show the second flyout
            $(this).parent().children('.js-callout-mainElement').find('a.js-callout-action').trigger('click');
        }
        else
        {
            //first click will select the list item, second click (and future first clicks) will open context menu
            console.log('missing markup. cannot call flyout #2');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

if you want to do some digging:

1. go to 15\layouts
2. backup clienttemplates.debug.js and clienttemplates.js
3. copy clienttemplates.debug.js to clienttemplates.js
4. play around with clienttemplates.js

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used 2013 enough yet to say whether or not this is definitive. But looking at the results of clicking on a Site Contents link, I see anchor tags for the ellipsis with a class like this: `ms-vl-calloutarrow ms-calloutLink ms-ellipsis-a ms-pivotControl-overflowDot js-callout-launchPoint`

Now it seems to me you could create your own hover function with jQuery and tie it onto the masterpage, something like:

```
$(".ms-ellipsis-a").hover(function(){$(this).click();});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JSLink** to solve this problem.

Register following JavaScript to you **LinkFilename** field via C#, PowerShell or any way. (I used C#.)

```
(function () {
    function RegisterFilenameFiledContext() {

        var linkFilenameFiledContext = {};
        linkFilenameFiledContext.Templates = {};
        linkFilenameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
            "LinkFilename": { "View": MyLinkFilenameNoMenu }
        };

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(linkFilenameFiledContext);
    }
    function MyLinkFilenameNoMenu(renderCtx, field) {
        // prevent rendering CALLOUT
        field.CalloutMenu = undefined;

        return ComputedFieldWorker.LinkFilenameNoMenu(renderCtx, field);
    }
    RegisterFilenameFiledContext();
})();
```

### How it works

As SharePoint renders **CALLOUT** according to `field.CalloutMenu`, just make it `undefined`.

*clienttemplates.js*

```
/* This calls rendering template. You can override by JSLink */
var retStr = field.fieldRenderer(renderCtx, field, listItem, listSchema);

/* many code here ... */

if (isCustomData == null || typeof isCustomData == 'undefined' || Boolean(isCustomData) == false) {
    if (field.CalloutMenu != null) {
        /* As CalloutMenu is set to undefined, this line will not be called */
        retStr = RenderCalloutMenu(renderCtx, listItem, field, retStr, IsCSRReadOnlyTabularView(renderCtx));
    }
    else if (field.listItemMenu != null) {
        /* This line will be called instead of RenderCalloutMenu */
        retStr = RenderECB(renderCtx, listItem, field, retStr, IsCSRReadOnlyTabularView(renderCtx));
    }
}
return retStr;
```

Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by editing the view through the UI.
http://blog.incworx.com/blog/consulting-from-the-trenches/disable-call-out-menu-in-sharepoint-2013-document-libraries

Or do it with PowerShell
[Sharepoint 2013: How to customize context menu view in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140378/sharepoint-2013-how-to-customize-context-menu-view-in-document-library)