# Sharepoint 2013: How to customize context menu view in document library

Tags: document-library

I want to customize the view of context menu in a document library.

So first image is what looks and second image is what i want, like context menu in lists. I mean i dont want the big box.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, or the equivalent in Powershell:

```
SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["YourListName"];
SPField field = list.Fields["Name"];
field.CalloutMenu = false;
field.CalloutMenuAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Prohibited;
field.ListItemMenu = true;
field.ListItemMenuAllowed = SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```